# Which Classifier would increase accuracy for text classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I have used the following code to classify. I am getting variable accuracy 55% to 60% .
I want to improve my accuracy up to 85%-90% .I am classifying into 8 different categories. What Steps I should take to improve accuracy.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
 from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
 from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
 from nltk import word_tokenize         
 from textblob import TextBlob


cov = pd.read_csv("F:/kipro/ml/dataset.csv", 
              names = ["Complaint", "target"])
cov.dropna()
s=pd.factorize(cov['target'])
cov['tarname']=s[0]
msk = np.random.rand(len(cov)) < 0.8
train = cov[msk]
test = cov[~msk]
train.dropna()
test.dropna()
y_train, y_test = train.tarname, test.tarname

def tokens(message):
   return TextBlob(message).words

def lemmas(message):
   message=message.lower()
   words = TextBlob(message).words
   return [word.lemma for word in words]

text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer=lemmas)),
                  ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                  ('clf-svm', SGDClassifier())
                ,])
text_clf = text_clf.fit(train['Complaint'].values.astype('U'),train['tarname'])
predicted = text_clf.predict(test['Complaint'].values.astype('U'))
x=np.mean(( y_test==predicted))*100
print(x)
```

Here is my screenshot of dataset
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxTla.png)

Comment: If you want a reasonably good answer, pls don't post snapshots of your dataset. Do you want us to reproduce the text for you as well? Look at some direction here: [Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To start, you can extract features from your text in some other way in addition to tf-idf.

Comment: I was trying with gridsearchcv but it takes lot of time to fit.Can you suggest me which feature extraction method should i use @VivekKumar

Answer (score 1):

Regarding classifiers :- 
Try using Naive Bayes Multinomial classifier. 
Svm is bit slow but it can increase the accuracy to few percentages. 
Also use n gram(2,3) approach at word level. 
Apart from these. XG boost (Extreme boosting ) is also a very good option. Just keep learning rate minimum, it will take time to train but your model will not overfit and will give good accuracy. Apart from these use stop words from nltk library. I think, you accuracy will be improved to some percentage. I'm not quite sure about the 85%+ accuracy but these implementations will definitely enhance the accuracy to a great extend.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Naive Bayes Classifier. It usually works for most text classification problems.